# How to convert Firebase data into custom Java object?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been reading the Firebase documentation, but it only shows simple examples. What I need to do is take all of the data from the root of my database and store it into an array of custom Java objects (for now, I am just trying to pull one survey into one object). Each child of the root is a Survey, and I have a class partially set up to take in the data.

I understand that I use this code:

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Survey s = childSnapshot.getValue(Survey.class);
            s.toString();
        }
    }
```

Here is my Survey.java class. I'm not sure exactly how to mirror the structure of the Survey objects in Firebase:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/*  This class stores one survey from the database  */
public class Survey implements Serializable {
    String name;
    String company;
    String description;
    String num_questions;
    String user;
    //HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> question_strings; // Stores question title as key, with an arraylist of answer choices as the value

    public Survey() { }

    public Survey(String name, String company, String description, HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> question_strings)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.company = company;
        this.description = description;
        //this.question_strings = question_strings;
    }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setCompany(String company) { this.company = company;}
    public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description;}
    public void setNumQuestions(String num) { this.num_questions = num;}
    public void setUser(String user) { this.user = user;}

    public String getName() { return this.name;}
    public String getCompany() { return this.company;}
    public String getDescription() { return this.description;}
    public String getNumQuestions() { return this.num_questions;}
    public String getUser() { return this.user;}

public String toString()
{
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Company: " + company);
    System.out.println("Description: " + description);
    System.out.println("Num questions: " + num_questions);


    return "";
}

}
```

And finally, here is a screenshot showing the structure of the objects in the database:
[image]

How should I structure my Survey class to work with Firebase?

Comment: Probably a bit late. But you don't construct your object based on your data, you construct your data based on the object. Because Firebase saves JSON, which isn't easy to changed types of things.

Comment: I can change the structure of my object

Comment: I see that you already have a serializable object, can't you just use `setValue` to store it in Firebase? Does it not work?

Comment: I don't need to store it in firebase, I need to pull it from firebase

Answer (score 1):

question_answers looks like a `List<List<String>>` to me. Did you try it?

Comment: Would it not be Map<String,Map<String,String>> ?

Comment: No, I don't think so, can you check it out?

Comment: I'll try it. Do I just make those fields in Survey.java and try it out?

Comment: Yes, as arrayList

Comment: Doesn't work. Made a quick implementation of toString for the survey, then added     ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> question_answers; and ArrayList<String> question_descriptions; to the Survey class, and it outputs nothing

Comment: Just noticed, seems like s.toString() never runs. I put a regular output statement in there and it never prints

Comment: Did you add getters, setters and constructor args for it? EDIT: so maybe debug if the method is even fired. It should be triggered when you add a new data.

Comment: I added some but not all. Also, I put a print statement before the for(Datasnapshot... part, and it didn't run. So it looks like the listener itself never even fires

Answer (score -1):

From what I see:

Company is a String

Description is a String

Name is a String

num_questions is an Int

User is a String

SurveryId is a long

question_answers is a bit complicated. But it seems to be a List of list of strings. So List>.

**P.S** num_questions seems redundant because you can already know the number of questions by getting the size of the question_answers list.